# how to convert Html block to dynamic widget?

Tags: customization, widgets

```
<div class="widget-wrapper">
      <div class="widget-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="widget-title">
      </div>
      <div class="widget-content">
      </div>
</div>
```

how to convert this to dynamic WordPress widget so that user can change the data and icon according to the needs and requirements.

Comment: It's a game of code: try to understand yourself first: (1) [`functions.php`](https://github.com/nanodesigns/nano-progga/blob/master/functions.php#L165-L202), and (2) [`sidebar.php`](https://github.com/nanodesigns/nano-progga/blob/master/sidebar.php)

Comment: Your question is really low quality. Please, see the [help center](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) and [how to ask](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).